# How can I set an insecure connections between endorser peers?

Tags: grpc, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go, endorsed

I am having problem with the Fabric SDK (fabric v. 2.2). It is working when I call from the terminal (peer chaincode query/invoke), but it cannot establish a connection with the other peers when I am using the golang SDK.

I had a similar problem with the client that I solved changing the address from grpcs to grpc (since TLS is disabled), so I strongly think that the SDK tries to build secure connection so it fails. I read I should set